# Getting differences of file between specific revisions/branches

Tags: grep, git, diff, git-log

I have 2 different branches A,B that have a (slightly different) version of a file X.
I am interested in getting the commits that added some specific patterns in branch B.
What I do roughly: `diff files| grep "^\+" | grep "$PATTERN" | for loop grep -n.. do git blame -L done`
This works but I was wondering if I am re-inventing/going a roundabout for something that is readily supported in git.
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can combine `git blame` and `git merge-base` to get the information you’re after:

```
git blame -n $(git merge-base A B).. -- file | grep -v "^^" | grep "$PATTERN"
```

This finds the common ancestor between A and B, then runs `git blame` on `file`, ignoring anything older than the common ancestor (the `..` notation tells `git blame` to look at revisions starting with the ancestor and ending at the current head). `-n` adds line numbers in the output. Then `grep -v "^^"` removes any lines which haven’t changed since the common ancestor, and finally `grep "$PATTERN"` looks for the pattern among only the lines which have changed. Since `git blame` in non-reverse mode only shows the lines currently in the file, the results will only include added or modified lines, which is exactly equivalent to your `^\+` filter.

Comment: 1) What are the `.`. after ` $(git merge-base A B)`? 2) Also when you say changed you mean `added/deleted/modified`? Because I am interested only in additions

Comment: This command verbatim gives the same output as my approach but I still don't get how it produces exactly the additions

Comment: I’ve expanded a little to address those questions. Note that your approach, as well as mine, include both added and modified lines; in your approach, modified lines are included because they appear as a `-` line (the old contents) followed by a `+` line (the new contents).

Comment: Where in git blame --help shows this option and that `^^` is for non-modified entries?

Comment: It’s not particularly obvious; see the description of `--abbrev`, and in particular “Note that 1 column is used for a caret to mark the boundary commit.” The indicator isn’t `^^`, it’s a single `^`; the `grep` filter is `^^` to filter on `^` at the start of a line (the first `^` is the beginning-of-line anchor, the second `^` is the caret we’re looking for).

Comment: The description for `--abbrev` says: `Instead of using the default 7+1 hexadecimal digits as the abbreviated object name, use
           <n>+1 digits. Note that 1 column is used for a caret to mark the boundary commit.` By reading at that it is not clear to me how I would understand what the command in your answer does. Just to be clear. I think your answer is awesome.

Comment: No worries, I understand where you’re coming from ;-). As is often the case the documentation isn’t clear on this topic, and I wouldn’t expect you to find how to do this by reading it... It’s a bit like signposts in some places, where instead of nice signposts at (or before) intersections, you only get signposts which confirm you’re on the right road *once you’ve figured out* what the right road is. I use `git blame` with revision ranges quite regularly, so I’m used to the caret indicating the boundary revision; `--abbrev` is the only place where that’s mentioned. I should submit a patch...

Comment: So the term `boundary revision` means changes across revisions? Also if this is not documented could the behavior change in the future?

Comment: A boundary revision is one of the bounds in the set of revisions `git blame` looks at (in this case, the merge ancestor). When `git blame` annotates a line with a boundary revision, it flags it with a caret because the information is incomplete — the real commit could be an older revision. I doubt it will change in the future; it *is* documented, albeit very obscurely. I’ll submit a documentation patch to improve the situation!

Comment: That would be amazing! If you can paste some link to have it as a reference it would be very helpful

Comment: Submitted [here](https://public-inbox.org/git/20180608193135.31110-1-steve@sk2.org/), let’s see if it’s accepted...